# rails reference model from variable name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, variable-assignment

i have some code that uses a string to determine dynamically what model class to use and for what field to find_by() on. however, i'm having a hard time with how to use these variables to get the model instance. specifically, i have

```
class Item
  include MongoMapper::Document
  key :my_variable, String
```

in my code i have

```
m = "Item"
f = "my_variable"
```

and i want to be able to

```
i = m.find_by_my_variable( f )
result = i[f]
```

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're in Rails (judging by the category tag) you can use:

```
m = m.constantize
```

to make the string a constant, and then would something like this work for your query?

```
m.where("#{f} = ?", some_value)
```

(EDIT) or use send as ismaelga suggested, if you don't want an ActiveRecord::Relation array object

Comment: Your answer is as valid as mine. It has just a different sintax. And actually it's a lil better. I would change a little instead of `where("#{f} = ?", some_value)` could be `where(f.to_sym => some_value)`

Answer (score 0):

You could do `eval(m.capitalize).send("find_by_#{variable_name}", variable_content)`

Capitalize it's only to be sure it gets a capital letter.